# h1 - Select second won't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having some troubles selecting the second h1. It works great if I try to select the first one, but the second one won't work. Could you take a look at it?

```
.sidemal h1:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 0px;    
}
```

I have tried to use !important, but didn't work.

Any ideas?

Link to site: http://tinyurl.com/pk9me6e

```
<section>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="page_title">Header 1</h1>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="col-md-12">
    ...
    <h1>Header 2</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that the second h1 is actually the second child of its parent.

Comment: I hope you are having an eye on your document outlines when using multiple h1-tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless your markup is literally:

```
<... class="sidemal">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    ...
</...>
```

...with no elements in between, your second `h1` element will not be the second *child*. If you want to select the second `h1` element, you can instead use the `:nth-of-type` selector:

```css
.sidemal h1:nth-of-type(2) { ... }
```

---

### Update

After looking at your page, there's no need to use any form of `:nth-` selector. Your second `h1` element is wrapped within an `article` element, whereas your first one isn't. Because of this, we can instead use:

```css
.sidemal article h1 { ... }
```

#### Demo

```css
.sidemal article h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidemal">
  <h1>First <code>h1</code> element</h1>
  
  <article>
    <h1>Second <code>h1</code> element</h1>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: A bit offtopic: the first `h1` doesn't have to be an `h1`. If it's an other element, the selector will work too (since it selects on children, not on type). The selector will also work with `<... class="sidemal">
    <p>Heading 1</p>
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    ...
</...>`

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Forgot to tell that I have also tried using `nth-of-type(2)`. Nothing works... I will edit my post and post a link to the site, if it's any help...

Comment: @Olen including your HTML in your question would be the best thing you can do here,

Comment: Very nice. Can't believe you saw it so fast. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

To select every second H1 you can use

```
.sidemal H1 + H1 { 
    margin-top: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: Or `.sidemal h1:nth-of-type(even)`.

Comment: @LinkinTED: That depends on how the reader interprets "every second H1". `H1:nth-of-type(even)` is not nearly the same thing as `H1 + H1`. Though I would think your suggestion matches that description.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes, you are right. The selector I provide will also target the second `h1` in this code: `<h1>...</h1><p>...</p><h1>...<h1>`, where the selector that Bas provides will only select a `h1` that has a `h1` directly before it.